# Is it possible to keep stdout intact in one process but still have a pipe to a second process?

Tags: c, unix, fork, pipe, file-descriptor

I am trying to make a logger for a program. For that reason I am having a second child process that is getting the parent's *stdout* via a pipe and using **tee**. Bellow is an example.

```
if (fork()>0){      //parent

  close(1);
  dup(pip[1]);
  close(pip[0]);

  char a[100]="";
  while (1){
    gets(a);
    puts(a);
  }

} else {           //child

  close(0);
  dup(pip[0]);
  close(pip[1]);

  execlp("tee", "tee", NULL);

}
```

This works fine. The child prints whatever I type in the parent using the pipe.

However is it possible to have the parent sending to *stdout* while simultaneously sending to the pipe?

Comment: Depending on the application size, you could also just use stderr for logging.

Comment: The logging is going to be for both stderr and stdout. At the time stderr and stdout print different things so I want to log both.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the man page for "write", then you can leave stdout open and write to both the the pipes:

```
while(1){
   gets(a)
   write(pip[1], a, len(a))
   puts(a)
}
```

Although you really ought to be checking your return values and all.

Comment: The thing is that I would prefer to not use `write` or any other function in the main program. That's why I try to make a whole new process for the logging so that nothing will be needed to be changed in the main program.

Comment: You could have your logger catching the information from the pipe, writing it to both std out and some log file...